# Java Box of Asterisks - just a line

Tags: java

This is college homework, I know I'm just missing something that should be obvious but I'm very new to this, so it's not obvious to me.  I need to create an empty box (outlined by asterisks) using Java, and nested loops.  No User input.  constants set at 4 wide and 6 long.

I have it all done except it keeps printing all the right stuff, in a straight line instead of making a box!  What did I do wrong?

```
final int NUM_ACROSS = 4;   // Number of asterisks to print across.
    final int NUM_DOWN = 6;     // Number of asterisks to print down.
    int row;    // Loop control for row number.
    int column; // Loop control for column number.

    // This is the work done in the detailLoop() method
    {
    for (row = 0; row < NUM_DOWN; row++)        
    for (column = 0; column < NUM_ACROSS; column++) 

        {
            if (column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS) 
            System.out.print("*");

            else if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN-1)      
                System.out.print("*");

                else  
                System.out.print (" "); 
        }       
        {       

                System.out.println();
```

Comment: Can you post something that compiles?

Comment: Your first for loop doesn't have the braces right.

Comment: If you are a beginner: do not omit braces just because you can. You'll end up investing hours on issues like this.

Answer (score 4):

This is why it's good practice to *always* surround blocks with curly braces, even if they're only one line. This is your code, correctly indented:

```
for (row = 0; row < NUM_DOWN; row++)        
    for (column = 0; column < NUM_ACROSS; column++) {
        if (column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS) 
            System.out.print("*");
        else if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN-1)      
            System.out.print("*");
        else
            System.out.print (" "); 
    }       
{       
    System.out.println();
```

Your `System.out.println(" ");`, which writes the new line, is *outside* of your for-loop, so it's only called once, at the end.

This is how the loops *should* be written:

```
for (row = 0; row < NUM_DOWN; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < NUM_ACROSS; column++) {
        if (column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN-1) {   
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print (" "); 
        }
    } // end inner for  

    System.out.println();
} // end outer for
```

**Explanation about braces**

In Java, if a for-loop or an if-statement only has a single line in it, it is technically OK to omit the curly braces. Therefore this is find:

```
if (column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS) 
    System.out.print("");
```

If there are two lines, however, the curly brackets are necessary:

```
if(column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS) {
    System.out.print("");
    doSomething();
}
```

An if-else if-else tree counts as a single "line" inside of a for-loop, so the curly brackets are technically not necessary. This is valid:

```
for (column = 0; column < NUM_ACROSS; column++)
    if (column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS) 
        System.out.print("*");
    else if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN-1)      
        System.out.print("*");
    else
        System.out.print (" ");
```

Likewise, that entire for-loop counts as a single line inside of the outer for-loop:

```
for (row = 0; row < NUM_DOWN; row++)        
    for (column = 0; column < NUM_ACROSS; column++)
        if (column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS) 
            System.out.print("*");
        else if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN-1)      
            System.out.print("*");
        else
            System.out.print (" "); 

// this line is inside of neither for-loop because of the lack of braces:
System.out.println();
```

In general, it is good practice for *all programmers*, regardless of level or ability, to surround their code blocks with curly braces to avoid ambiguity in syntax. This practice of omitting braces can become dangerous when in a situation with multiple programmers, or even badly indented code. Consider the code in the original post -- could you tell, at a glance, what nested where or was included in which loop?

Another example where the lack of curly braces could have unintended consquences. Consider a situtation where you need to print "First half" if the day is less than 15, and print "November" if the month is 11. The following code

```
if ( day < 6 )
    System.out.println("First half.");

if ( month == 11 ) 
    System.out.println("November.");
```

Let's say the project requirements change and you're no longer supposed to print out "first half" if the day is less than 15. Some helpful intern comes in and comments out that line:

```
if ( day < 15 )
    // System.out.println("First half.");

if ( month == 11 ) 
    System.out.println("November.");
```

Is this OK? No! Now you've broken your case for November as well, because the above code is semantically equivalent to this:

```
if (day < 15)
    if (month == 11)
        System.out.println("November.");
```

If we'd been using curly braces all along, we'd be fine:

```
if (day < 15) {
    // System.out.println("First half.");
}
if (month == 11) {
    System.out.println("November.");
}
```

There's undoubtedly half a dozen other reasons and examples as to *why* this is best-practice. Getting into the habit of always using the curly braces, even it if means typing a few extra characters every so often, will undoubtedly help you keep your code working as expected and cut down on the number of compilation and other errors you may encounter.

Comment: +1 "it's good practice to always surround blocks with curly braces"

Comment: I see!  I had curly braces at one time, then took them out because it still wasn't formatting right, but now I see it is because my system out print ln was outside all of them anyway.  SO it would have never created a box.... I did not realize the second for statement needed to be in it's own brace but I see the necessity for that now.

Comment: @ValerieDurrantPurvis The inner `for` loop has to be inside the block of the outer `for` loop. The `if` statement has to be inside the inner `for` loop's block etc.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL Very much!  That was exactly the problem!  Are the braces then, the cue for the program to go to the next step? or to look for additional instructions?

Comment: @ValerieDurrantPurvis - OK this is how it is in Java: if you have a block that only has a *single line*, then you can omit the braces. So `if(someting) doSomething();` is valid. But if you have multiple lines inside the block, you *must* include braces. In your outer for-loop, you have *two* things inside of it: a for-loop and your `System.out.println()` statement. Since you omitted the braces on the outer loop, the compiler assumed that the only thing inside the for loop was the first thing it found inside: the inner for-loop.

Comment: In general, it is good practice to *always* use curly braces on blocks, *even if they're not technically necessary.*

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas  THANKS!  Your explanation is adding to the clarity I am gaining.  It is important for people to understand they whys as much as the wherefores of these things.

Comment: @ValerieDurrantPurvis - I updated my answer to add a bit of discussion about usage of curly braces.

Comment: Thank you!  I like long explanation because then I can "see" it emerging..... I'll be back!  Probably this weekend.  I want to work on it a little first before I cry UNCLE! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (row = 0; row < NUM_DOWN; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < NUM_ACROSS; column++) {
        if (column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS) 
            System.out.print("*");
        else if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN-1)      
            System.out.print("*");
        else  
            System.out.print (" "); 
    }  
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Is this resolve your problem ? (put the `System.out.println();` into first loop) ?

Comment: The temptation for the op to copy/paste your code and submit it as the answer is great.  She'll get a 100% score on it, and she'll not have learned how to program at all.  Learning instead to post it on stack overflow with the comment: "Just tell me what to type".  We are doing her a dis service by giving her the answer.  We should instead be directing her to sites that talk about How to write code that compiles.  How to fix off-by-one errors.  How braces work.  How to problem solve and how to properly indent your code.  She needs to learn how to solve it herself, and we are preventing that.

Comment: Ok, I understand what do you mean and I'll remember it. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It was how my braces were placed.  I have it now.  THanks for the response.

Comment: No Eric, my code compiled, I just didn't post it all because I didn't think you all would want the whole thing.  I know better now. It just didn't have proper bracketing, and by showing me how it should be braced it reinforced what I've read for days!  All people cannot learn by reading, some people have to be shown and told why a thing has to be done. Thank you emmensly for your concern though.  If I weren't 46 years old this might be easier! I have alot of catching up to do!

Comment: If you are indeed using this site as help to do homework for college, don't get too addicted to it, legions of people will give you the answers, and you'll get great grades, and find yourself unemployable at the end of your college education because the employers will give you a problem to test your problem solving skills, and you will be sunk without access to stack overflow to do it for you.  The biggest I see you don't yet understand is java scope and how the for loop works: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @EricLeschinski If I hadn't already spent 4 days on the project before this one I probably wouldn't have bothered to come to a site like this, but after reading tons and tons I still didn't see the error of my ways, I have to come for help! I will look at that website and bookmark it for sure!  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you reformat the code to make it more readable, the error becomes more obvious:

```
for (row = 0; row < NUM_DOWN; row++)        
    for (column = 0; column < NUM_ACROSS; column++) {
        if (column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS)
            System.out.print("*");
        else if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN-1) 
            System.out.print("*");
        else 
            System.out.print (" "); 
    }

{ //What's this brace doing here?      
    System.out.println();
```

The outer `for` loop (that iterates over each row) does not have an opening brace defined in the correct position. Because the `for` statement is not followed by an opening brace, the body of the for loop is *just* the next statement (ie. the inner `for` loop).

The opening brace afterwards simply forms a block around the `println()` statement. To avoid this problem, I personally prefer to put the opening braces on the same line as `for` and `if` statements to avoid accidentally inserting anything before the block. I also recommend putting braces around one-liner if-statement bodies, to avoid confusion should an additional line be added at a later date. See the following for an example:

```
for (row = 0; row < NUM_DOWN; row++) {   
    for (column = 0; column < NUM_ACROSS; column++) {
        if (column == 0 || column == NUM_ACROSS)
            System.out.print("*");
        else if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN-1) 
            System.out.print("*");
        else 
            System.out.print (" "); 
    }           
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I see!  The braces at the end of the lines were confusing to me at first.  THank you for the explanation.  I also had a 1 that should have been a 0.  All is well now.  Thank you for your help! I saved your reply so I would remember next time!